# sql запрос к БД для получение по одной строке из каждой группы

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно создать sql запрос к базе данных, чтобы получить по одной строке из каждой группы (первое вхождение), а также все строки без группы?

таблица со строками
products, ключевое поле id

пример таблицы: products с полями id и title

```
----------------------------
id | title 
----------------------------
12 | THC20-10
13 | HnW-150
18 | EcoNG150-010
19 | THM180-007
20 | EcoNG150-015
21 | EcoNG150-010
22 | THM180-010
23 | THC20-15
25 | MST-1
```

таблица, где хранится информация о группах links

пример таблицы links с полями master slave

```
------------------------
master | slave
------------------------
12 | 23
18 | 20
18 | 21
19 | 22
20 | 18
20 | 21
21 | 18
21 | 20
22 | 19
23 | 12
```

входные значения список всех id 
12,13,18,19,20,21,22,23,25

что нужно получить:

```
12 THC20-10
13 HnW-150
18 EcoNG150-010
19 THM180-007
25 MST-1
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите как или натолкните на мысль как правильно это сделать, спасибо!

Comment: Добавьте ваш вариант запроса, который не получился или не работает

Comment: непонятно, что вы хотите получить. Почему 20 не вошло? каким образом происходить связь друг с другом - id к master?

Comment: @Denis Похоже, что в `links` хранятся ребра графа (причем зачем-то ориентированного), вершины которого - продукты. А группы - это области связности этого графа.

Comment: @Denis, потому что этот товар связан с группой EcoNG150 18 | 20

Comment: @Denis суть в чем, есть каталог товаров, товары сгруппированы связями друг с другом, нужно вывести первый совпавший товар из бд, возможно тут придется использовать другую связь?

Comment: Пока что ваше задание всё равно остается непонятным.